# Build a two-dimensional (Recycler)View with elements which span multiple cells

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm breaking my head on what would be the best way to develop this element:
- It has to scroll horizontally and vertically as a whole
- It consists of multiple rows: uneven rows are headers, uneven rows have blocks which represent one hour
- The blocks must be clickable
- An event can span multiple time units en show a text or images on that span

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

[image: Sketch]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GridLayoutManger with desired `number of columns`. Then use

```
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                case MyAdapter.HEADER:
                    return <number of column>;
                case MyAdapter.ITEM:
                    return 1;
                default:
                    return -1;
            }
        }
    });
```

For more details see this SO post:

[RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and first element with different viewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411053/recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-and-first-element-with-different-viewholder)

This will give you a better understanding.

Simple!!